# "i3 exec" Not Working When Used With Xbindkeys Shortcut

Tags: shell, xbindkeys, dmenu

I am making a "dmenu" shell script that will read a list of my VPN connetions and pipe them through dmenu.
After the user selects the appropriate entry we call "nmcli".

Bellow is the script.

```
#!/bin/sh

export vpn_name=$(echo -e "OFF\n$(nmcli -f NAME,TYPE con show | awk '$2 == "vpn" {print $1}')" | dmenu -p "Connect to VPN:" -i -l 20)

if [ "$vpn_name" == "OFF" ]; then
  nmcli -f NAME,TYPE,ACTIVE con show | awk '$2 == "vpn" && $3 == "yes" {print $1}' | xargs nmcli con down
else
  echo "executing else" >> /tmp/vpn
  i3-msg "exec --no-startup-id \"$TERM --hold -t 'Connect to VPN'\""
fi
```

Now my problem is that when I run the script from xbindkeys, nothing happens..

```
bindsym $mod+Shift+v exec ~/.local/bin/dmenu/vpn.sh
```

I have tested running it normally from my terminal (alacritty) and everything works fine.

What might be the reason that makes i3 not run the exec command when xbindkey shortcut is used ?

PS: My env is

i3 version 4.23
Linux 6.7.9-arch1-1 (x11)